# Logitech G600 MMO Gaming Mouse - debian logout

Tags: debian, logitech-mouse

When I press any button on said mouse it logs me out...

Comment: welcome to superuser! Your question is a bit short on context, to get a meaningful answer you could add info on, for example, version of Debian and your hardware. See the FAQ for this site. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is the right format to add my experience, wasn't sure about the improve question feature.
I recently purchased the same mouse and experienced the same problem when booting into Ubuntu.
I use a 10.08 distribution of Ubuntu.  I dual boot along side Windows 7.  My Laptop is an ASUS G74SX-A1.  The mouse is fully functional in Windows with the exception that the Logitech Gaming Software used the program the buttons on the mouse does not detect the mouse.  I booted into Ubuntu to see if I would have any better luck and discovered that when I pressed any button on the mouse, the screen would have a brief garbled graphic and then go straight to the login screen, regardless if I was already at the login screen or already logged in.
Based on how the drivers in Windows appear and the functionality of the mouse, sorry I don't know this for a fact, the mouse appears to have an onboard controller that interfaces with the mouse and keyboard aspect of the mouse and stores the programmed button configurations.  I am assuming this is where Ubuntu is having the issue because it sees this controller before the mouse and if Ubuntu does not have a driver for the controller the signals from the controller is sending a misinterpreted signal to Ubuntu that is causing it to go the the login screen.
Hope this helps.